# How to read code block after a function call?

Tags: swift

I am new to swift, I need help in reading the following code.

1. what is the meaning of the code block after the function call "self.table.update(completedItem)" {...}
2. what is the meaning of (result , error) in as the first line of the code block:

   self.table!.update(completedItem) {
                   (result, error) in
    //... come code
    }

full code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let record = self.records[indexPath.row]
        let completedItem = record.mutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary
        completedItem["complete"] = true

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        self.table!.update(completedItem) {
            (result, error) in

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            if error != nil {
                println("Error: " + error.description)
                return
            }

            self.records.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The code block is called a “trailing closure”.  When a function or method takes a closure as the last argument, you can put the closure after the closing parenthesis of the function/method call.  The trailing closure lets you write functions that look more like built-in control structures, and lets you avoid nesting braces inside parentheses.

For example, `UIView` defines a class method with this signature:

```
class func animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, animations: () -> Void)
```

So you can call it like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    self.view.alpha = 0
})
```

or you can call it with a trailing closure, like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
    self.view.alpha = 0
}
```

Note that with a trailing closure, you entirely omit the keyword (`animations:`) of the last argument.

You can only use a trailing closure for the very last argument of the function.  For example, if you use `UIView.animateWithDuration(animations:completion:)`, you must put the `animations:` block inside the parentheses, but you can use a trailing closure for the `completion:` block.

2. The `(result, error)` part declares names for the arguments to the block.  I deduce that the `update` method has a signature something like this:

   ```
   func update(completedItem: NSMutableDictionary,
       completion: (NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)
   ```

So it calls the completion block with two arguments.  To access those arguments, the block gives them the names `result` and `error`.  You don't have to specify the argument types because the compiler can deduce the types based on `update`'s declaration.

Note that you can in fact omit the argument names and use the shorthand names `$0` and `$1`:

```
self.table!.update(completedItem) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    if $1 != nil {
        println("Error: " + $1.description)
        return
    }

    self.records.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
}
```

You can learn more about closures by reading [“Closures” in *The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).